# Interactive borkers - requesting market data

Tags: interactive-brokers, ib-api

I'm having a bit of a disaster trying to do something simple - in short getting ib api to work. I'd like to get the current market prices for a stock on the LSE, I've subscribed to the correct market feed and ran this code:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
import threading
import time

from ibapi.contract import Contract

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType == 2 and reqId == 1:
            print('The current ask price is: ', price)

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()

app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 4002)

#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

#Create contract object
apple_contract = Contract()
apple_contract.symbol = 'BARC'
apple_contract.secType = 'STK'
apple_contract.exchange = 'LSE'
apple_contract.currency = 'GBP'

#Request Market Data
app.reqMktData(1, apple_contract, '', False, False, [])

time.sleep(10) #Sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data
app.disconnect()
```

However I'm getting this error back:

```
The current ask price is:  -100.0
unhandled exception in EReader thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient\ibapi\reader.py", line 34, in run
    data = self.conn.recvMsg()
  File "C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient\ibapi\connection.py", line 99, in recvMsg
    buf = self._recvAllMsg()
  File "C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient\ibapi\connection.py", line 119, in _recvAllMsg
    buf = self.socket.recv(4096)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

If anyone can help, it'd be greatly appreciated! Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the -100 is because the exchange is closed.  The error can be ignored, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684561/2855515

It seems like your code is working fine even if a little unorthodox.

Comment: My lord! That's akin to not turning the computer on! Works perfectly, thanks Brian. Out of interest why do you say a "little unorthodox"?

Comment: sleep()  is ok for testing code but I wouldn't use it.  You should start the requests after getting a nextValidId callback so you know the connection is working.  Then I would disconnect after getting an ask price or some timeout, not a sleep.  I also wouldn't use 4002 as a client Id since you might get confused with ports but technically no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late for answers to this post,  but could be useful to someone getting tired of IBApi  which is still got so many complications and they add up more in each versions. I tried IBApi_insync which is better to use IBApi asynchronously. I tried a few myself and updated here,

[https://github.com/cosmoarunn/ib_insync_examples/](https://%20%20%20%20https://github.com/cosmoarunn/ib_insync_examples/)

see if it fits.